# How To Root Samsung A510F?

Tags: rooting, samsung

I have tried Framaroot, Universal Android Root, IRoot, Z4Root, TowelRoot  and obviously, kingroot. I also attempted to try chainfire's auto root but could not find a compatible file to flash for my device. Here's the link to chainfire's list of compatible devices [Chainfire Auto Root](https://autoroot.chainfire.eu)

Here is the screenshot of my device software info

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try rooting with TWRP.

- Download TWRP Odin flashable [here](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=3314399)
- Download Odin [here](http://odindownload.com/mobile/)
- Boot in download mode with POWER + HOME + VOL DOWN
- Connect the phone
- Flash with Odin 3.10.7. Select the downloaded file using the AP slot. Uncheck Auto-reboot.
- Reboot to recovery immediately after flashing using POWER + HOME + VOL DOWN, as soon as the screen goes blank change to VOL UP whilst still holding the other buttons.
- TWRP should now boot
- Flash the file below in twrp. 
  DO NOT LET TWRP ROOT YOUR DEVICE WHEN IT ASKS FOR. USE ONLY THE FILE BELOW:
  [Root Chainfire SU](https://download.chainfire.eu/921/SuperSU)

NOTE 1:  FLASHING CUSTOM STUFFS VOIDS YOUR WARRANTY. AND THIS WILL TRIP THE KNOX FLAG.

NOTE 2: ENABLE OEM UNLOCK FIRST OR YOU MAY ENCOUNTER 'BLOCKED BY FRP LOCK' WHEN FLASHING. 
*Settings > Developer Options > OEM Unlocking*

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer! However, is it possible to flash a custom recovery without root and pc?

Comment: On some devices root is not needed, on others it is a must. I've never tried flashing a custom recovery without a PC. Flashing a stock recovery through a custom recovery seems possible though.

Comment: What do i need to make sure such that I will not brick my phone? There was once i attempted to root my phone by flashing chainfire auto root using odin and ended up bricking my phone. I got it fixed by taking to Samsung and they said the motherboard was spoiled.

Comment: I cannot assure you if i gonna work or not.

Comment: Is it possible to turn my phone into a emulator on the pc? I would like to test it on an emulator first if possible.I know I am asking to many questions but I am just not confident that all will turn out well.

Comment: I don't know or even don't think this could be possible. But if you don't feel confident, just do not attempt anything.